# Использование $ и _ в идентификаторах в Java

Tags: java

Есть ли соглашения о том, где использовать $ и _ в именовании идентификаторах(кроме использования _ в качестве разделителя слов)? Если да, то в каких случаях использовать эти символы?

Comment: Ни разу не видел чтобы их вообще использовали

Comment: В Java ни тот ни другой символ не используется при именовании переменных, в том числе и в качестве разделителя слов

Answer (score 5):

Есть такое соглашение - Java Code Style ([тут оригинал](https://google.github.io/styleguide/javaguide.html)). При возникновении вопросов советую сверяться с ним. По сути же вопроса - использование этих символов не запрещено, но не нужно так делать.
Собственно, можно и по-русски переменные называть, Вам же это в голову не приходит :)
Для разделения слов в названии джависты используют camelCaseWords. Что же до $... забудьте про него, если Вы пишете на java